# Datatype for storing audio files in SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want my C# app to allow clients to upload and download audio files and they must be stored in the database. Which is the suitable datatype in SQL Server that I should use?

Comment: c# - byte array, database - varbinary.

Answer (score 2):

With EntityFramework CodeFirst byte[] will automatically map to varbinary(max)

```
public class AudioFile
{
    //TODO: DB generated
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //This will automatically map to varbinary(max)
    public byte[] FileData { get;set; }
    public string LocalFileName { get;set;}
    public string MIMEType {get;set;}
}
```

Although you're using a general byte[] to store, you can add more encapsulation with the class for specialisation. There's no need for any Audio datatype for the actual FileData field.

```
public partial class AudioFile
{
    public void Play()
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

**Thinking of just SQL Server and the best datatype**

**Varbinary(max)** is the best type to use for storing binary data for all file types. This excludes consideration of **FileStreaming**, and also excludes storing files separate to the database in a **Folder**.

**Varbinary Limitation** - If you're going to store a lot of these Audio streams, and you're using SQL Server Express, you'll soon reach your 10GB limit. You can continue partitioning with more databases, but in general it's a bad idea to store file data in database fields.

If you're just starting a prototype application, or the first versions, keep the scope down.

**FileStream** is a great option. It takes a bit to configure on SQL Server if it's your first time.

But I often opt for my own **file folder**. It's much simpler in a Web Application context, where one can expose that file folder directly for static file downloads and CDN caching (depending on sensitivity of the information).

In conclusion:

- Out of simple fields, the best to choose is varbinary(max)
- varbinary(max) is also the quickest to get going
- you can convert later *when* it becomes a problem, but I'm sure you're building something more than an AudioFile Data Store, and should be building more of the other critical features first.